# JQuery scrollTo with overflow: auto

Tags: jquery, overflow, scrollto

I'm designing a mobile webpage and the following piece of CSS HAS to be present in order for the `position: fixed` items to work properly:

```
html, body { height: 100%; overflow: auto; }
```

However, after adding `overflow: auto`the scrollTo() method doesn't work anymore - no scrolling happens. Why is that? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issues with needing `overflow: auto;` but it was because I was previously scrolling the window rather than the element I wanted to scroll. Switching to the element worked with updated positioning.

So instead of:

`$(window).scrollTo()`

I switched to:

`$('#element').scrollTo()`

And that worked. I'm not sure if you're in exactly the same situation but it may help?

Comment: This solution doesn't work for me, because I need to scroll the entire window.

Comment: Ah. If using fixed positioning for certain element(s), can you not have a wrapper around the elements that will scroll and target that with scrollTo? It may not be possible though, depending on your markup.